# Most efficient (and pythonic) way to count False values in 2D numpy arrays?

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

I am trying to count `False` value in an `np.array` like this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[True,True,True],[True,True,True],[True,False,False]])
```

I usually use this method:

```
number_of_false=np.size(a)-np.sum(a)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: How about using `numpy.count_nonzero`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala is the same using numpy.sum no? Just count the True

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`count_nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html#numpy-count-nonzero) to count non-zero (e.g. not `False`) values:

```
>>> np.size(a) - np.count_nonzero(a)
2
```

Comment: Yes but this is not the same solution that I use more or less?

Comment: and from my little benchmark, by an order of magnitude at that. :)

Answer (score 13):

The clearer is surely to ask exactly what is needed, but that doesn't mean it is the most efficient:

Using `%%timeit` in `jupyter` with python 2.7 on the proposed answers gives a clear winner:

```
    seq = [[True, True, False, True, False, False, False] * 10 for _ in range(100)]
    a = np.array(seq)

    np.size(a) - np.count_nonzero(a) 1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.34 µs per loop  - Antti Haapala
    (~a).sum()                        100000 loops, best of 3: 18.5 µs per loop  - Paul H
    np.size(a) - np.sum(a)             10000 loops, best of 3: 18.8 µs per loop  - OP
    len(a[a == False])                 10000 loops, best of 3: 52.4 µs per loop
    len(np.where(a==False))            10000 loops, best of 3: 77 µs per loop    - Forzaa
.
```

The clear winner is **Antti Haapala**, by an order of magnitude, with `np.size(a) - np.count_nonzero(a)`

`len(np.where(a==False))` seems to be penalized by the nested structure of the array; the same benchmark on a 1 D array gives `10000 loops, best of 3: 27 µs per loop`

Comment: Btw: `a.size` is ~10x faster than `np.size(a)`. An alternative to benchmark could be `np.count_nonzero(~a)`, which will not be the most efficient, though.

Answer (score 5):

This would do that:

`len(np.where(a==False))`

Maybe there are other ways that are faster or look better.

Answer (score 3):

One alternative would be:

```
np.bitwise_not(a).sum()
```

Even shorter, but maybe less clear is:

```
(~a).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

### Count Number of False Compare

```
number_of_false = np.size(out_putArray) - np.count_nonzero(out_putArray[0] >= out_putArray[1])
```

### Count of Numbers of True Compare

```
number_of_true = np.count_nonzero(out_putArray[0] >= out_putArray[1])
```

Comment: What is `out_putArray`? Your code seems will not work. It should be `number_of_true = np.count_nonzero(arr1 >= arr2)`. Not using the index.